# How is the difference in ground and excited state of baryons masses explained within QCD and SM?

Tags: standard-model, higgs, quantum-chromodynamics, elementary-particles

How is the difference in ground and excited state of baryons masses ($\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^*$, $\Xi$ and $\Xi^*$ for example) explained within QCD and SM? Is it possible to calculate (predict) this mass difference for each individual case? Is it possible to predict the particles masses with respect to the Higgs field (Higgs boson mass)?

Comment: I don't know a complete answer to the question, but the majority (about 99%) of the contribution to baryon masses is due to binding energy from the strong force, rather than interaction with the Higgs field. Theoretical analysis of baryon masses is currently only possible using Lattice QCD due to the nonperturbative nature of the strong force, so I would expect that the answer to your question is no, but I'm not an expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higgs couplings will only determine the current quark masses of your system, a small correction to your spectroscopy, unless your Baryons have a heavy quark subscript like *c* or *b*, in which case, again, the Higgs has done its job, and all that is left is the nonperturbative strong interactions at work.

The specific baryon mass differences you are referring to are due to hyperfine interactions in QCD, which can be accommodated as in Section IV.B.3 of

- Klempt, Eberhard, and Jean-Marc Richard (2010): "Baryon spectroscopy." *Reviews of Modern Physics*  **82** no. 2  , p. 1095,

see the chromomagnetic spin-spin term of eqn (30).

Comment: Appreciate the extensive answer. Much appreciated. Will most likely tick it if no answer comes in a couple of days.
Thank You very much.